# Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot emit new states after calling close Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using `Cubit` and trying to get data through `Dio` and this my method

```
void getShopGift(int categoryID) async {
    emit(GetShopGiftsLoadingState());

    AppConstants.token = CacheHelper.getStringData(key: 'token');
    emit(GetShopGiftsLoadingState());
    await DioHelper.postData(url: GIFTS, data: {
      'category_id': categoryID,
      'token': AppConstants.token,
      'lang': cachedLang
    })!
        .then((value) {
      shopGiftModel = ShopGiftModel.fromJson(value.data);
     

      emit(GetShopGiftsSuccessState());
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      emit(GetShopGiftsErrorState());
    });
  }
```

[and this is cubit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5RdG.png)

```
I/flutter ( 6609): Change { currentState: Instance of 'GetShopGiftsLoadingState', nextState: Instance of 'GetShopGiftsLoadingState' }
E/flutter ( 6609): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot emit new states after calling close
E/flutter ( 6609): #0      BlocBase.emit (package:bloc/src/bloc_base.dart:96:9)
E/flutter ( 6609): #1      RehlatechCubit.getShopGift.<anonymous closure> (package:rehlatech/layout/cubit/rehlatech_cubit.dart:633:7)
E/flutter ( 6609): #2      FutureExtensions.onError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:1013:24)
E/flutter ( 6609): #3      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1658:54)
E/flutter ( 6609): #4      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:22)
E/flutter ( 6609): #5      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:778:47)
E/flutter ( 6609): #6      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:799:13)
E/flutter ( 6609): #7      Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:557:7)
E/flutter ( 6609): #8      _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:47:12)
E/flutter ( 6609): #9      Future.any.onValue (dart:async/future.dart:613:45)
E/flutter ( 6609): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6609): #10     Future.any.onValue (dart:async/future.dart:612:5)
E/flutter ( 6609): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6609):
```

and this my blocprovider

```
import 'package:conditional_builder_null_safety/conditional_builder_null_safety.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:rehlatech/models/shop_gift_model.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';
import '../../../layout/cubit/rehlatech_cubit.dart';
import '../../resources/assets_manger.dart';
import '../../resources/color_manger.dart';
import '../../resources/routes_manger.dart';
import '../../widgets/shop_gift_card.dart';
import '../drawer/navigation_drawer_screen.dart';

class ShopGiftScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ShopGiftScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var cubit = RehlatechCubit.get(context);
    ShopGiftModel? model = cubit.shopGiftModel;

    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => RehlatechCubit()..getCachedLang(),
      child: BlocConsumer<RehlatechCubit, RehlatechState>(
        listener: (context, state) { },
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Scaffold(
              drawer: const NavigationDrawerScreen(),
              body: Builder(
                builder: (context) {
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                    physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Stack(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 35.h,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                                        Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                                        BlendMode.dstATop),
                                    image: const AssetImage(ImageAssets.widget),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(35),
                                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(35)),
                              ),
                              child: const Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child:
                                    Image(image: AssetImage(ImageAssets.logoBlack)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                              child: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.menu_rounded,
                                    color: ColorManager.black),
                                onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                              child: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {

                                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                                        context, Routes.gifts);
                                  },
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                                    color: ColorManager.black,
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 1.h),
                        ConditionalBuilder(
                          condition: model!=null && state is! GetShopGiftsLoadingState,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => ListView.separated(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              physics:const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() ,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ShopGiftCard(
                                shopGiftData:model!.data![index],
                              ),
                              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(),
                              itemCount:model!.data!.length),
                          fallback: (BuildContext context) => Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              backgroundColor: ColorManager.white,
                              color: ColorManager.primary,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
              ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcbap.png)

Tried to change states and delete it and change method type as a Future

Comment: Please provide the source code of you, do not use screenshots

Comment: Can you post your BlocProvider code?

Comment: @rrttrr i added my BlocProvider, sorry for being late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `BlocProvider` from `ShopGiftScreen` and add it to `MyApp()` in the `main.dart` page, above `child: MaterialApp`.

After the change, `MyApp()` should look like this

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<RehlatechCubit>(
          create: (context) => RehlatechCubit(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Then convert `ShopGiftScreen()` to a Stateful Widget. Inside its `initState()`, call `context.read<RehlatechCubit>().getCachedLang();`.

Comment: didn't work with me same error

Comment: Edited, try that too.

Comment: how can i connect with you in private ? rrttrr